# How to fill a preceding non-null value when using time window in TDengine?

Tags: sql, tdengine

I have a SQL statement that counts every second of status in TDengine.

```
SELECT 
  first(ts), 
  voltage 
FROM 
  d1 
where 
  ts >= '2017-07-14 10:40:00.000' 
  AND ts <= '2017-07-14 10:41:00.066' INTERVAL(1s)
```

There are 3 seconds of data that are missing, as shown in the figure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoBal.png)

If there is no value, I would like to use a previous non-null value in the query instead. So I tried to add a `FILL(PREV);`. However, the result doesn't look right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y0gu.png)

How do I modify this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT 
  _wstart, 
  first(voltage) 
FROM 
  d1 
where 
  ts >= '2017-07-14 10:40:00.000' 
  AND ts <= '2017-07-14 10:41:00.066'
  INTERVAL(1s) FILL(PREV)
```